# js indexOf not working with numbers

Tags: jquery

I need to check if div A's data value contains div B's data value and if so apply a class to div B, note there are many div B's.

```
HTML:
<div class="a" data-num="1,2,3,4,5">div A</div>
<div class="b" data-num="3">div B</div>
<div class="b" data-num="6">div B</div>
<div class="b" data-num="1">div B</div>

JQUERY:
$('div.b').each(function(){
var a_num = $('div.a').data('num');
var b_num = $(this).data('num');

if ($(a_num).indexOf(b_num)) {
  $(this).addClass('special');
}
});
```

I thought the above would work, but it doesn't. Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems...first of which is `indexOf()` always needs to be compared to `-1` since `0` is a valid index but is also falsy

Your concept would work if you used array for div A value. Otherwise you are simply doing string comparisons and `10,11,12` would all return a valid index when checking using `1`

Finally don't wrap the data in `$()`. It's not dom related

You could do

```
<div class="a" data-num="[1,2,3,4,5]">div A</div>
```

or convert to array using current format and using `split()`

```
var a_num = $('div.a').data('num').split(',');
```

And for both cases you must use comparison to `-1`

```
 if (a_num.indexOf(b_num) >-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own function here because `indexOf` will not work.

```js
function isFound(arr,num){
  fnd = false
  for (n=0; n<arr.length; n++){
    var bb = parseInt(num);
    var aa = arr[n];
    aa = parseInt(aa);
    if (aa==bb) fnd=true;
  }
  return fnd;
}
$('div.b').each(function(){
  var aa = $('.a').data('num').split(',');
  var bb = $(this).data('num');
  var tst = isFound(aa, bb);
  
  if (tst) {
    $(this).addClass('special');
  }
});
```

```css
.special{color:red;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" data-num="1,2,3,4,5">div A</div>
<div class="b" data-num="3">div B</div>
<div class="b" data-num="6">div B</div>
<div class="b" data-num="5">div B</div>
```